# PCB footprint of Xilinx Kintex 7 FPGA

Tags: fpga, footprint, allegro, kintex-series-fpga

I am laying out a board with a Xilinx Kintex 7 FPGA (serial number XC7K70TFBG676). The first step is to create a footprint of the FPGA for my layout tool, the Cadence Allegro PCB Editor.

Does Xilinx provide Allegro footprints of their FPGAs for easy import?

Comment: Have you tried the Xilinx web site, or asking Cadence?

Comment: How is asking Xilinx or Cadence not the obvious answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not even necessary for you to ask xilinx, since someone else has done so already. A quick google search ("xilinx kintex footprint") gives me [this](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/7-Series-FPGAs/Kintex-7-footprints/td-p/237280) as the third result, where a Xilinx employee states that the

> Kintex-7 FF676 is the same as every other Jedec 1.0mm 27x27 device, so the PCB decal footprint is the same.

Which indicates that the footprint of that specific kintex is standard. The only difference between the FFG and the FBG is the thermal characteristic and the height of the package, so the statement above should apply to the FBG also.

Since the part is standard, some tools have a part creation feature where it is possible to specify the package type and pitch and other dimensions and the tool will create the part for you.

Comment: Search the footprint libraries supplied by Allegro; you will probably find a suitable one. If not, in most PCB layout systems it's not difficult to create; which is important as your PCB manufacturer or board assembly contractor may have specific requirements in terms of pad size or soldermask clearance that differ slightly from the "standard". This is definitely worth checking before proceeding to manufacture...

Comment: @Randomblue, I know that some tools have quite a nice footprint generator function where you can specify that it's a BGA and the dimensions and it will generate the part for you.

Comment: Mentor bought a very nice footprint generator from PCBLIbraries which generates an IPC-compliant footprint from dimensions you read of the datasheet and exports it in a bunch of different formats.  Recommended if you do much PCB work.  PCBLibraries has now also reformed with new software... haven't used that yet